# Is there a way to handle server connections individually in go?

Tags: go, websocket

I would like to be able to handle each connection individually in a go webserver. I would also like to limit the number of connections to 2. I would think WebSockets would be a start but I don't know how to do this. Any lead helps.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/ - namely the `Listen` example at the very beginning.

Comment: If you think that websockets might be start, search for [websocket at pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=websocket) and take a look at the most imported package. The documentation links to examples that might help you get started.